# Missing library wit libGDX? [IntelliJ]

Tags: android, game-engine, libgdx

I wish to start developing android games, so I was trying to set up libGDX with IntelliJ.
I used [this link](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx) from the wiki to setup everything but it's not working.

It says that I'm missing a library but they're are present in the classpath and all the module dependencies are set correctly.

Am I missing something?

This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 32-bit
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:104)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglNativesLoader.load(LwjglNativesLoader.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:76)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:64)
at it.enrichman.game.DesktopStarter.main(DesktopStarter.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:102)
... 10 more
```

and these the classes in the modules:

Android:

```
public class MySimpleGameTest extends AndroidApplication {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
      cfg.useAccelerometer = true;
      cfg.useCompass = false;
      cfg.useWakelock = true;
      cfg.useGL20 = true;
      initialize(new TestGame(), cfg);
  }
}
```

Desktop:

```
public class DesktopStarter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
      cfg.title = "Title";
      cfg.useGL20 = true;
      cfg.width = 800;
      cfg.height = 480;
      new LwjglApplication(new TestGame(), cfg);
  }
}
```

and Main:

```
public class TestGame extends Game {

Texture carImage;

  @Override
  public void create() {
      carImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("car.png"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must import library  gdx-natives.jar after import gdx.jar, I have meet the same question.